# Eclipse RCP : make a standalone plugin extending an existing standalone one

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have extended via extension point (add menus and functionnalities) an already existing plugin which has it's own product definition file and it's own class Application implements IApplication.
    I want to create a Product Configuration(customize splash screen,etc...). Does my plugin need an Application class?
     I want my plugin to be independant, Standalone with a launcher. Not a fragment. Do I have to inherit already existing plugin Application? 
     Thanks for the tips and tricks.

Comment: Hello Greg. No, existing plugin is not using Eclipse 4. I have searched for an existing xmi file. Nothing. What I consider now is to get an example with Application Class, Activator and product file and insert my code in it. It s not state of the art architecture....Humm have you any other good tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to declare your own `product` (using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point) specifying the existing `application` id.

So, for example, to can declare your product like this:

```xml
<plugin>
   <extension
          id="product"
          point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
       <product
             name="My product name"
             application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
     .... more ....
```

This example is using the existing application id for the Eclipse E4 application declared in an existing plugin using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point.

If the application you are extending is based on Eclipse 4 your product definition will need to include a property for the application XMI file:

```xml
<property
       name="applicationXMI"
       value="plugin id/Application.e4xmi">
 </property>
```

You will need to look at the existing product definition to find the location of the XMI file.

You may also need properties for the CSS file, theme and resources.

Comment: My own plugin does not have any Application class. I have create a new plugin and plug myself to extension point of already existing plugin which has an Application class. can you give a shot sample?

Comment: The existing plugin will have used the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` to define an application id, you just need to reference this in your product definition. No need for your own Application class. Updated answer

Comment: Hello Greg, thank you for your help. The process seems to go further. Nevertheless, I got : org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Application.e4xmi

Comment: Hello Greg, thank you for your help. The process seems to go further. Nevertheless, I got : org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Application.e4xmi    ...according to what I have read .e4xmi are for fragment but I just create a plugin based on another plugin

Comment: Is the application you are extending using Eclipse 4?

Comment: Added details about properties for Eclipse 4 XMI file

Comment: Hello Greg. No, existing plugin is not using Eclipse 4. I have searched for an existing xmi file. Nothing.

Comment: Check the application id - you must find the id for the existing app, you can't use the example I used in the answer.